# com.jayway.jsonpath.InvalidPathException: Invalid path $myVar.id

Tags: java, json, java-8, mockito, jsonpath

In my mockito test case i'm using the below snippet ,

```
this.mockMvc.perform(get(myURL + myId).param("mock", "false").param("filter","false")).andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(jsonPath("$myVar.id", is(SOME_ID)));
```

at this line i'm getting the below error ,

```
com.jayway.jsonpath.InvalidPathException: Invalid path $myVar.id
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.PathCompiler.compile(PathCompiler.java:76)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.<init>(JsonPath.java:98)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.compile(JsonPath.java:374)
    at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.<init>(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:62)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.JsonPathResultMatchers.<init>(JsonPathResultMatchers.java:63)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath(MockMvcResultMatchers.java:202)
    at com.mypackage.MyTest.testMyMetod(MyTest.java:232)
```

and FYI,

i'm using the json-path and json-path-assert as a dependency with below version 
1.1.0

and i tried the latest version 2.4.0 and also the very old version 0.8.1

But i got the same issue.

Help will be really appreciated.

Comment: what is your json response?

Answer (score 3):

It is look like path should be `"$.myVar.id"` or `"myVar.id"`. According to [source](https://github.com/AndersDJohnson/JsonPath.java/blob/master/json-path/src/main/java/com/jayway/jsonpath/internal/PathCompiler.java) of `PathCompiler` they are equal.

Comment: I ahve to use in this format  `.andExpect(jsonPath("$['myVar'].id", is(SOME_ID)));`

Comment: @Tanveer Yes. This is another syntactically valid expression.

Answer (score 0):

I have to use below pattern matcher in jsonPath,

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$['myVar'].id", is(SOME_ID)));
```